# file uploading using jquery

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I am trying to upload file using [this jquery library](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload), it is working fine, but I want some thing more than that, the problems I am facing are like it upload file right after I choose file, I want to make validation before uploading (validation like type and size of file), also I want to call the file uploading function in some other function, I am stuck here any help will be appreciate-able regards

Comment: I have tried its basic version, which uploads the file asynchronously, but I want to do some validation before uploading it also I want to call file uploading function in some other function

Comment: you can create your own  in the same time you trying to modify bluimp uploader... its too confusing and with bunch of file

Comment: You can try using [HTML5 File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/).

Answer (score 1):

Basing on documentation of project, you should override `add` function.

> **add**
>
> The add callback can be understood as the callback for the file upload
>   request queue. It is invoked as soon as files are added to the
>   fileupload widget - via file input selection, drag & drop or add API
>   call.

Default behaviour is:

```
function (e, data) {
    data.submit();
}
```

Moreover there's already file type and size validation within plugin:

> **maxFileSize**
>
> The maximum allowed file size in bytes, by default unlimited.
>
> **minFileSize**
>
> The minimum allowed file size, by default undefined (can be 0 bytes).
>   **acceptFileTypes**
>
> The regular expression for allowed file types, matches against either
>   file type or file name as only browsers with support for the File API
>   report the file type.

So you don't need to do it yourself

Answer (score 1):

Solution with [Uploadify Plugin](http://www.uploadify.com/):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.uploadify.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function () {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'swf': '/Scripts/uploadify.swf',
            'uploader': '/Home/UploadFile',
            'fileTypeExts': '*.gif; *.jpg; *.png', //type limitations
            'fileTypeDesc': 'Image Files',
            'fileSizeLimit': '100KB' //size limitation
        });
    });
</script>


<input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />
```